# SQL query to LINQ or Lambda

Tags: c#, sql, linq, lambda, entity

I have the following query

```
SELECT sdb.student_due_by_month_id, sdb.due_month_year, sum(sdb.due_total_month) FROM user_student ust
INNER JOIN student std ON ust.student_id = std.student_id
INNER JOIN student_due_by_month sdb ON std.student_id = sdb.student_id
WHERE ust.user_id = 2
GROUP BY sdb.student_due_by_month_id, sdb.student_due_by_month_id, sdb.due_month_year
```

I need to convert it to linq or a lambda expression.
I'm trying to turn him into a linq and this is what I have so far:

```
 var user_due_month = await (from ust in _context.Users_students
                                    join std in _context.Students on ust.student_id equals std.student_id
                                    join sdb in _context.Students_dues_by_months on std.student_id equals sdb.student_id
                                    where ust.user_id == user_id
                                    group sdb by new { sdb.student_due_by_month_id, sdb.due_month_year } into g //from here i have yet to complete the linq query, help?
```

I don't know what would be missing to complete my linq query correctly, and also be able to pass it to a viewmodel.

Thanks a lot!!

Comment: I'm not sure what you are asking.  Are you asking for someone to fill in your ellipsis (the three dots `...`).  Your `from` code that you show will return an `IQueryable`.  So you can't `await` it (it's not a Task).  You'll need to await`ToListAsync` or something similar to get the results from the query.

Comment: What I need is a functional linq query based in my sql query

Comment: Start with a simple query to get the pattern. Then add more complexity.

Comment: This is the linq I've been carrying so far: `from ust in _context.Users_students
                                    join std in _context.Students on ust.student_id equals std.student_id
                                    join sdb in _context.Students_dues_by_months on std.student_id equals sdb.student_id
                                    where ust.user_id == user_id
                                    group sdb by new { sdb.student_due_by_month_id, sdb.due_month_year } into g`

Comment: Perhaps my [SQL to Linq Recipe](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49245160/sql-to-linq-with-multiple-join-count-and-left-join/49245786#49245786) might help you.

Comment: Seems like you just need to add `select new { g.Key.student_due_by_month_id, g.Key.due_month_year, due_total = g.Sum(sdb => sdb.due_total_month) }`